# Stream decompress file for reading in Windows transparently

Tags: windows, compression, csv

I have a collection of compressed, very large .csv files from which I need to extract some small subset of the contents. Let's not focus on possible practical solutions, but rather on the following *theoretical* question:

**Is there any way of transparently stream-reading the contents of a compressed file in Windows?** The goal is to read a .zip (or other format) file as if it was a .csv file, from a program that only knows how to deal with .csv files.

In Linux you can create a bash script that triggers a decompression and sends it to a named pipe upon reading. In Windows I think you can create one with OS APIs, but I'd like to know if there's some easier way. Also, I don't know how you'd read it from another program that only knows how to read files.

Thanks!

Comment: This was asked over on StackOverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37561465/how-to-read-contents-of-a-csv-file-inside-zip-file-using-powershell

Comment: @AtomicFireball Thanks! But how do I use that PowerShell code to read the csv from a program that only knows how to read csv files?

Comment: The answer shows how to extract a single file. You could do that to a temporary directory and use `Import-CSV` to read the file in PowerShell. You could also use [System.IO.Compression]'s entries property to get a list of the names and search for any CSV files before extracting them. `Expand-Archive` is also available in PowerShell 5.